# Zabbix external checks

Tags: zabbix

I am executing an external check which returns me: OK 1 2 0 8 (This values will change every check)

Does anyone knows how can I separate this values into items?

Example:

```
External check status: OK
In use: 1
Busy: 2
Problem: 0
Free: 8
```

As each one of the above would be an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to destructure a received string value into parts using standard Zabbix means for all item types.

However, some items like `vfs.file.regexp[]` support applying a regular expression and capturing its output (see [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) for details). In this case, you could write the output of your script into a file and then create five items, approximately as follows:

```
vfs.file.regexp[/tmp/file.txt,^(\w+),,,,\1]
vfs.file.regexp[/tmp/file.txt,^\w+ (\w+),,,,\1]
vfs.file.regexp[/tmp/file.txt,^\w+ \w+ (\w+),,,,\1]
vfs.file.regexp[/tmp/file.txt,^\w+ \w+ \w+ (\w+),,,,\1]
vfs.file.regexp[/tmp/file.txt,^\w+ \w+ \w+ \w+ (\w+),,,,\1]
```

Comment: Its not the best way... but it worked fine.. thanks... If someone knows another way please let us know.